# python possesive quantifiers in re

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following expression in regex101 with PERL marked up. It works. But it does not work in python with re.

```
pattern = [0-9]{1,4}+(?![\.\/\-][A-Za-z]{2,})[A-Za-z]
```

What I am looking for is to catch numbers followed by a letter but NOT numbers followed by more than a letter.

Explanation:

- [0-9]{1,4}+ digits up to 4 with a possessive quantifier
- (?![./-][A-Za-z]{2,})negative look ahead: Which are not followed
  by 2 or more letters
- [A-Za-z] a letter

The result is as follows:
[image]

All fine, but this is marking up PERL in the regex101 website, as soon as I mark python:
[image]

The possessive + symbol is not recognize.

One option is to resort to the library regex:
https://pypi.org/project/regex/

but this is an suboptimal solution since re is part of the standard package.

Is there anyway to reproduce this + behavior in normal python regex (re)?

thanks

EDIT: To be clear, this other regex DOES NOT SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

```
pattern2="[0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z]{2,})"
```

because it catches a number and the first letter, what I want if that the regex gives me nothing if the number is followed by more than one letter.

Comment: The point is to disallow a digit after the digit matching pattern, add `\d|` alternative into the negative lookahead. However, `\b[0-9]{1,4}[A-Za-z]\b` looks enough here.